# Infinite set is dense set in cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Define $$\tau = \{U \subset X; U^c \ \text{is finite or} \ U=\emptyset\}.$$
Let $X$ be an infinite set and  $Y \subset X$ be an infinite subset of $X$. Prove that $Y$ is dense in the cofinite topology and that $(X,\tau)$ is separable.

My attempt:

Let $x \in X$ and $O$ be an open set that contains $x$. Using the definition we have that $X\setminus O$ is finite. If $Y \cap X=\emptyset$, then $Y \subset X\setminus O$ which is absurd. So $Y$ intersects $O$ and, as $x$ is a neighbourhood of $O$, $x \in \overline{Y}$ and we have $\overline {Y}=X$.

Is this enought or we have some mistake?

For the second part, i don't know to prove that $(X,\tau)$ is separable, any hint?

Comment: Where you write *as $x$ is a neighbourhood of $O$* you actually mean *as $O$ is a neighbourhood of $x$*. I would say *as $O$ is an **arbitrary** neighbourhood of $x$*: the fact that this applies to every nbhd of $x$ is crucial. Otherwise it’s fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is enough (I would change the phrasing "is absurd" - but I am not a native english speaker)
2. "For the second part, i don't know to prove that $(X,\tau)$ is separable", you just did prove it - think about the definition of separable space.

Comment: My definition for separable spaces is: If $Y\subset X$ is dense and enumerable, then $(X,\tau)$ is separable. I don't really get when i proved that $Y$ is enumerable.

Comment: $Y$ isn't necessarily enumerable but what you have proved is that every infinite set is dense. Since $X$ is infinite it follows that... (basic set theory result)

Comment: @shortmanikos: The phrasing *is absurd* is fine and not uncommon in this context.